# Efficient update of SQLite table with many records

Tags: c++, python, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite (sqlite3) for a project to store hundreds of thousands of records (would like sqlite so users of the program don't have to run a [my]sql server).

I have to update hundreds of thousands of records sometimes to enter left right values (they are hierarchical), but have found the standard

```
update table set left_value = 4, right_value = 5 where id = 12340;
```

to be very slow. I have tried surrounding every thousand or so with

```
begin;
....
update...
update table set left_value = 4, right_value = 5 where id = 12340;
update...
....
commit;
```

but again, very slow. Odd, because when I populate it with a few hundred thousand (with inserts), it finishes in seconds.

I am currently trying to test the speed in python (the slowness is at the command line and python) before I move it to the C++ implementation, but right now this is way to slow and I need to find a new solution unless I am doing something wrong. Thoughts? (would take open source alternative to SQLite that is portable as well)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create an index on `table.id`

```
create index table_id_index on table(id)
```

Comment: Wow, that seems to have worked. Why and where can I read more about it?

Comment: An overview of the SQLite3 optimizer is at http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

Comment: @blackrim: Same page: http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html#indexes

Answer (score 3):

Other than making sure you have an index in place, you can checkout the [SQLite Optimization FAQ](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html).

Using transactions can give you a very big speed increase as you mentioned and you can also try to turn off journaling.

Example 1:

> 2.2 PRAGMA synchronous
>
> The Boolean synchronous value controls
>   whether or not the library will wait
>   for disk writes to be fully written to
>   disk before continuing. This setting
>   can be different from the
>   default_synchronous value loaded from
>   the database. In typical use the
>   library may spend a lot of time just
>   waiting on the file system. Setting
>   "PRAGMA synchronous=OFF" can make a
>   major speed difference.

Example 2:

> 2.3 PRAGMA count_changes
>
> When the count_changes setting is ON,
>   the callback function is invoked once
>   for each DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE
>   operation. The argument is the number
>   of rows that were changed. If you
>   don't use this feature, there is a
>   small speed increase from turning this
>   off.

Comment: Found that page, but those didn't seem to help too much. Maybe shaving a second here or there, but only about 1% or less.

Comment: Worth noting that PRAGMA count_changes has been deprecated.