# How to update multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The table looks like this:

```
status1   status2   status3   element
  0         1         2       music1
 ...
```

My script extract hundreds of thousands of rows like this, do some processing with them and then write back the new status. The problem is, if i update these rows one by one like this:

```
UPDATE music_table
  SET status1 = '10',
      status2 = '20,
      status3 = 30
WHERE element = 'music1';
```

It would take an awful lot of time to finish all. (over 1.5 hours!!)

So the question is, how do I update multiple rows at the same time or is it even possible?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838790/efficient-update-of-sqlite-table-with-many-records help?

Comment: It is possible to update multiple rows at once. But it depends on relations with other tables. Do you have other tables that have relations with the table above?

Comment: @Blair: Never thought it could be just this easy. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @naoki: Yes. It's an independent table.

Comment: Also SQLite sets rather low values for the memory cache these are fine for embedded usage but write performance can be greatly increased if the cache size is increased when the memory is available. See the pragmas.

Comment: How is this 'some processing' done? Does it follow the same rules for *all* rows?

Answer (score 0):

Having an index on the `element` columns make it faster to find the row, if you update one row at a time.

However, it is also possible to update multiple rows at a time, if you can do the computation of the new status in an SQL expression:

```
UPDATE music_table SET status1 = status1 + 1
```

(This changes the status of all rows; you can still use `WHERE` to restrict the update to some rows.)

If the computation is more complex, you can register a *user-defined function*:

```py
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3

def compute_status1(a, b, c):
    return a + b + len(c)

db = sqlite3.connect(...)
db.create_function("compute_status1", 3, compute_status1)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute('UPDATE music_table SET status1 = compute_status1(status2, status3, element)')
cur.close()
```